# How to stop showing warning optimize css delivery on google page speed tool

Tags: wordpress

How to stop showing warning optimize css delivery for the https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=www.moneytap.com%2F  .I am trouble to find any solution to remove these warning  only for the css. I make defer all css but still I am getting warning with google page speed

Comment: those warnings are there because all those css calls are blocking the display of the site – until all css is fully loaded. 
Instead of writing an essay about it ;-) The best resource to learn about above the fold techniques: https://css-tricks.com/authoring-critical-fold-css/

Comment: I make async call for all css  and google page speed tool warning has stop but  at the time of page loading getting page fatal css